# Implementing a database search

Tags: django, search, django-models, django-haystack

Currently I have a database of Courses, and it has 6 columns:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    Cat1 = models.BooleanField()
    Cat2 = models.BooleanField()
    Cat3 = models.BooleanField()
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
```

The unicode method for this course is made to output something like:

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.department, self.number, self.title, 'CAT1' if self.Cat1 else '','Cat2' if self.Cat2 else '','Cat3' if self.Cat3 else '')
```

Which returns something like: ENG 1104 Academic Writing Cat1 Cat3

I'm trying to implement a search to find courses by text queries, so I tried Haystack (with Whoosh as the engine), but to make it easier to index I just added a new column to the model named `text`, in which I just added the Unicode text of each course. This method works pretty well, but obviously its not robust and because this is only a small project of me for learning purposes, I would like to know more efficient ways of accomplishing this search. Any Ideas?

Comment: U can try MYSQL full tet search http://www.mercurytide.co.uk/news/article/django-full-text-search/

Comment: Also, FWIW. When you're passing in that many variables to a string interpolation, it's better to use named parameters, i.e. `u'%(department)s' % {'department': self.department}`. You can spread the dictionary over multiple lines, making it much more readable, and you can see at a glance what info is going where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haystack doesn't require any changes to your models. The recommended method is to use a template:

```
class CourseIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    ...
```

Then, you create a file named in the form of `templates/search/indexes/[app]/[model]_[indexfield].txt`. So, in this case it would be `templates/search/indexes/yourapp/course_text.txt`. Then, you use standard Django template tags and such to create a plain text representation of your model:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.number }}
{{ object.department.name }}
```

Add as much info as you like. If you have any rich text fields that include HTML, remember to use `striptags`, so you don't end up with garbage in your index.

Comment: This would work with the exception of the Cat1,2,3 fields, which are Boolean but when searching I want to search for the actual name. Can I write something like {{'CAT1' if object.Cat1 else ''}} in the template?

Comment: Sure, something like, at least. It works just like a standard Django template, so what you have won't work, just because it's not valid syntax for a Django template, but `{% if object.Cat1 %}CAT1{% endif %}` will work.

Comment: Also, the idea here is simply to add any keyword to the template you might want people to find it by. The spacing, line endings etc. don't matter. This isn't being *viewed* like a standard template, it's just getting fed into the index as the content for a full-text search.